# 2013 Mac Pro RAM upgrade not much faster

Tags: upgrade, memory, mac-pro

I have a 2013 Mac Pro 10.10.2 running on Yosemite. I upgraded the RAM to 64GB(4X16) and it doesn't seem to be much faster while processing FCPX files. Are there any settings I can check to ensure it's running at top speed?

Comment: More RAM doesn't equal faster processing.  Having more RAM enables you to keep more "stuff" in faster memory rather than going to disk (swap), but there's a caveat:  if you weren't maxing out your memory to begin with, adding more will make no difference.  It's like having 1 liter of liquid in a container with a 2 liter capacity and upgrading the container to 3 liters with the expectation it will pour out faster.

Comment: thank your for the input, it's very much appreciated! After looking at my activity monitor I am using the full 64GB I installed, and as I type the transcoding is idle because I'm maxed out before even doing that task...

Comment: Post a screenshot of activity monitor to you question.   64GB is a lot of memory to fill up

Answer (score 1):

Processing files requires CPU/GPU power. More ram helps by caching the files in memory, but your bottleneck probably is the CPU (or maybe a slow storage, if you're using external disk).

Also upgrading to the latest macOS version could help, since FCP X is using Metal, and Metal 2 is incorporated in High Sierra.

Answer (score 0):

You can open Activity Monitor in the utilities folder and check if the extra RAM is being utilised.

Comment: As I type this I am maxed out on the RAM per the activity monitor and FCPX is idle for transcoding as I'm already using all of it...